# How to compare two List String?

Tags: java

I'm very new to java and I have two `List<String>`. When I do :

```
list1.equals(list2)
```

is giving me `false`. Eventhough the list are same.

Is it the right way to check the equality?

Comment: we have to know your definition of `equals`

Comment: Include code that will let us reproduce your problem. Otherwise we would only have to guess what could be wrong and that means a lot of guessing.

Comment: Please post example input and output.

Comment: The `String.equals()` method, the one that `List<String>` uses to check equality, is well-defined, so -**if** they are in the same order- the comparison needs to yield `true`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`isEqualList`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-3.2.1/org/apache/commons/collections/ListUtils.html#isEqualList%28java.util.Collection,%20java.util.Collection%29) from Apache's [`ListUtils`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-3.2.1/org/apache/commons/collections/ListUtils.html):

> isEqualList

```
public static boolean isEqualList(java.util.Collection list1,
                                  java.util.Collection list2)
```

> Tests two lists for value-equality as per the equality contract in
>   List.equals(java.lang.Object).
>
> This method is useful for implementing List when you cannot extend
>   AbstractList. The method takes Collection instances to enable other
>   collection types to use the List implementation algorithm.
>
> The relevant text (slightly paraphrased as this is a static method)
>   is:
>
> Compares the two list objects for equality. Returns true if and only
>   if both lists have the same size, and all corresponding pairs of
>   elements in the two lists are equal. (Two elements e1 and e2 are equal
>   if (e1==null ? e2==null : e1.equals(e2)).) In other words, two lists
>   are defined to be equal if they contain the same elements in the same
>   order. This definition ensures that the equals method works properly
>   across different implementations of the List interface. Note: The
>   behaviour of this method is undefined if the lists are modified during
>   the equals comparison.

Comment: I don't see how that helps vs List#equals in this specific case...

Comment: Agreed with @assylias , I do not see what is wrong with the standard implementation.

Answer (score 1):

It is the correct way. Your lists are not equal as you say they are. Try printing them for visual inspection.

Comment: So basically you are saying that this should work and if it is not it means that there is something wrong with lists and OP should print them to see problem? It seems [more like a comment to me rather than answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118992/are-works-for-me-answers-valid).

Answer (score 1):

For two lists to be equal, they need to have the same order. I can only assume that you want to ignore the ordering of the two lists when considering equality.

For a comparison that ignores order, you can compare two `Map<String, Integer>` instances (where the `Integer` is the count per string).

eg:

```
public <T> boolean isEqualIgnoreOrder(List<T> l1, List<T> l2) {
   if (l1.size() != l2.size()) {
      return false;
   }
   Map<T, Integer> m1 = createMap(l1);
   Map<T, Integer> m2 = createMap(l2);
   return m1.equals(m2);
}

protected <T> Map<T, Integer> createMap(List<T> list) {
   Map<T, Integer> map = new HashMap<T, Integer>();
   for (T item : list) {
      Integer prevCount = map.get(item);
      map.put(prevCount == null ? 1 : prevCount + 1);
   }
   return map;
}
```

This type of collection is known as a bag. More discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15608667/why-no-bag-directly-implemented-in-java-collection-framework)